# Java Websocket: Unable to retrieve HttpSession and PrincipalUser from HandshakeRequest object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-ee-7, java-websocket

This is my custom Configurator implementation:

```
public class TokenStore extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {

    @Override
    public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
        super.modifyHandshake(config, request, response);

        HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) request.getHttpSession();  //NULL
        String token = request.getHeaders().get("token").get(0); //NULL
        String name = request.getUserPrincipal().getName(); //NULL
    }
}
```

I have registered `TokenStore.java class in @ServerEndpoint as a configurator`. When a connection is established to a server, I am not able to retrieve `httpSession`, `token` and user principal. All these properties is being received as null inside `modifyHandshake()` function.

What am I doing wrong here?

- Do I need to send user principal and token from client side? If yes,
  how?
- Why this HttpSession is null even though a connection between client
  and server is established successfully?

Comment: There is no session, and therefore no user principal, until the handshake completes.